# Editable Data table in request scop JSF2.0

Tags: jsf-2

Hi All
      I have list of module object. I want to show it to user and user can edit it and can save it also. In module object three members are there 1 String moduleName 2.boolean readFlag
3. writFlag.

The bean i am using is in **Request Scop**  i don't want to use any other scop.
My problem is setterOfThatList is not called when update button is clicked.
Where as on the same page i used another inputText, setter of the variable which is connected to this inputText is called.

```
<h:dataTable value="#{roleBean.listMatrixDo}" var="list">
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Module Name"></h:outputText>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{list.moduleDo.moduleName}"></h:outputText>
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Read Access"></h:outputText>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{list.readFlag}" />
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Write Access"></h:outputText>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{list.writeFlag}" />
                </h:column>
            </h:dataTable>
```

Comment: Could you add the part containing the update button and the other inputText?

Answer (score 0):

> *My problem is setterOfThatList is not called when update button is clicked*

The setter is **never** called for collection and nested properties. JSF does basically as follows:

```
((RowObject) bean.getList().get(rowIndex)).setSomeProperty(submittedValue);
```

It gets the list and then gets the row object by current index and then sets the property on it. As you see, it's important that the very same list is already prepared in the subsequent request (i.e. you need to do it in constructor/postconstruct of the bean).

This is regardless of the scope. In view and session scope, however, you don't need to prepare the list in subsequent requests. I'd recommend to use the view scope when data loading from the DB is been involved.

If your intent is to process/save the submitted data, then you should just do the job in the bean's action method which you attached to the commandbutton.

```
public void submit() {
    someService.save(list);
}
```

Comment: **Thanks A lot BalusC** <p>What if we use request scop and instead datatable we use ui:repaeat with html table  cant't this be achieved ?? which one would be better </p>  **THANKS Matt Handy**  I want to know details about JSF 2.0 so that i can understand why particular thing are happning please suggest me book tutorial etc....

Comment: The `ui:repeat` will also not invoke the list setter. I really don't understand why it is so important for you that the list setter is invoked. You shouldn't do any business actions in getters/setters anyway. It look like a plain misconception from your side. You should then reframe the question to elaborate about the functional requirement for which you incorrectly thought that letting JSF to invoke the list setter is the solution.

Comment: Thanks **BalusC** for reply. I do not bother about getter or setter as called.As you can see from my code i am trying to update it, but when i am clicking Update button i am not getting values in list , list is empty. my only concern is that i want less number of DB hit as well as less load on server ie performance should be good.As we know Session scope would do what i need but again that is not good . I will try view scope.

Comment: Hi **BalusC** IF bean is in Viewscope and not implementing Serelizable is throwing exception am i correct or doing sth very wrong